# OpenApi default array with values

Tags: java, api, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I am using OpenApi 3.0.0 with openapi-generator 4.2.2.
Is there a way to define a default value for an array with a value?
I want to be able to pass an array of enums, but if it wasn't passed I'd like to give it a default array with one of the enum values.

This:

```
Request:
  type: object
  required:
    - fix_types
  properties:
    fix_types:
      type: array
      items:
        type: string
        enum: [ ALL_FIELDS, FIELD1, FIELD2 ]
      default: [ ALL_FIELDS ]
      description: What fields should be fixed
```

is not working, I am getting an empty array, aka [].
Is there a way to do what I want?

Comment: Do you mean you used openapi-generator to generate a server stub, and the generated code doesn't initialize the default value for `fix_type`?

Comment: Indeed. 
Instead of getting my defined `default`, an empty array was generated (the default for required properties as I understand).

Comment: @JsonProperty("fix_types")
  @Valid
  private List<FixTypesEnum> fixTypes = new ArrayList<>();

Answer (score 0):

Your array definition is correct. This looks like an issue with the `openapi-generator`. You can open an issue or search for existing issues here:
https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues